# Sending mail via smtp in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, smtp

I have been using SMTP library [smtp](https://github.com/jetseven/skpsmtpmessage/blob/master/SMTPLibrary/SKPSMTPMessage.m)

But this library although useful, is somewhat problematic when used in arc environment. I have been having trouble sending large images while using library in arc.

Is there some alternative for this in ARC?

Comment: Why don't you just turn off ARC for the library?

Comment: I did, without that it cant compile.

Comment: Judging by the library code, the library doesn’t support ARC, it uses the old manual memory management. So what does it exactly mean that it’s “problematic in ARC environment”? Does it leak? Are you sure?

Comment: Did you disable arc only for the lib? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project